# making stream Lambda Expressions in Java8

Tags: list, lambda, java-8, java-stream

1 3 2 4 5 8 9
When there is a list of these numbers
Give me the lambda expression which makes a new list with the second largest number of three.
Ex) 1 3 2 -> 2 / 3 2 4 -> 3 / 2 4 5 -> 4 / 4 5 8 -> 5 / 5 8 9 -> 8
-->making the list with  2 3 4 5 8

```
List<Integer> li = new ArrayList<Integer>(1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 8 ,9);
while(true) {
  final List<Integer> newli = li.stream()
   .limit(3).sorted().collect(ArrayList::new, ArrayList::add,  ArrayList::addAll);
  li.remove(0);
  total += newli.get(2);
  if(li.size()<3)
   break;
  }
```

Please let me know how to use the other method instead of using the loop
that's ok using Man-made function

Answer (score 1):

Well I can think of this way:

```
 List<Integer> li = Arrays.asList(1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 8, 9);

    IntStream.range(0, li.size() - 2)
            .mapToObj(i -> li.stream().skip(i).limit(3))
            .map(x -> x.sorted().skip(1).findFirst().get())
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: @장수환 thx. But on stack overflow thx means this:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work